# Error in getting input in structure using gets()

Tags: c, arrays, structure, gets

I am making a program to take input in teacher structure but there is unknown run time error , here is the code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Teacher
{
 char Name[30];
 char Qualifications[20];
 int experience_year;
}th[10];

void teacher()
{    
 int t,i;
 printf("Enter how many teachers are in department\n");
 scanf("%d",&t);
 for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
 {       
   printf("Enter name of teacher : ");
   gets(th[i].Name);
   printf("Enter qualification of teacher : ");
   gets(th[i].Qualifications);
   printf("Enter experience_year of teacher : ");
   scanf("%d",&th[i].experience_year);
 }
 for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
 {
   printf("Details of %d teacher\n",i);
   printf(th[i].Name);
   printf(" ");
   printf(th[i].Qualifications);
   printf(" ");
   printf("%d",th[i].experience_year);
   printf("\n");
 }
}   
int main()
 {
   teacher();
   return 0;
 }
```

Output is -

```
Enter number of teacher
1
Enter teachers name : Enter qualification of teacher :
```

How to get teacher's name(input).. and what is the error ?

Comment: The main error here is that you're using `gets`. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @szczurcio not to mention even _thinking_ of using `conio.h` ;)

Comment: @szczurcio , That won't solve the problem, though.

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, this is why it's a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: You never use the first index of `th`(Arrays in C are 0 based,i.e, indices start from 0 and end at length-1). Also, check the value of `t` to prevent out-of-bounds.

Comment: As arrays start with zero, use `for(i=0;i<t;i++)`. Don't forget to check `t<=10`.

Comment: This unknown thing also happen when i was using for(i=0;i<10;i++)  ,, but now i got my answer , thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
getchar();
```

before

```
 gets(th[i].Name);
```

to consume leading whitespaces and newlines, which were left in the buffer due to previous statements.

Also, I would recommend `fgets`, which is safer than `gets` as:

```
fgets(th[i].Name,30,stdin);
```

and

```
fgets(th[i].Qualifications,20,stdin);
```

[Why gets is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: Hardcoding the buffer size in `fgets` is bad IMO, `sizeof(th[i].Name)` is better.

Comment: @szczurcio: Yes you are right, I just gave a simple example, though I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

First a remind for good and bad pratices :

- thou shall not use `gets` - only `fgets` is good
- thou shall not mix `[f]gets` and `[f]scanf` - only stick to one input mode

Now let's be serious.

`gets` tries to put in your input array as many characters as are present in input stream : it used to be the cause of countless memory violation. **Never use it** and only use `fgets` in you want to deal with line mode input (but do not forget that the input of `fgets` keeps the terminating `\n`)

`[f]scanf` is used for blank delimited fields. That is it reads a field until next blank character (at least space, tab, `\r` or `\n`) and **leaves it in input stream**. You can try to skip over that using a `fgets` and discarding what was read, or reading character by character until a `\n`. Avoid it because you got a number of *bad* answers advising to use a single `getchar()`. That's always the first try, and it works until you get an input with (unvisible) spaces before the newline - just try it and you will understand why it is a wrong solution.

So what should you do ? If input is line oriented, only use `fgets`, and then decode the input values with `sscanf` :

```
void teacher()
{    
 int t,i;
 char line[16];
 printf("Enter how many teachers are in department\n");
 fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
 sscanf(line, "%d",&t);
 for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
 {       
   printf("Enter name of teacher : ");
   fgets(th[i].Name, 30, stdin);
   printf("Enter qualification of teacher : ");
   fgets(th[i].Qualifications, 30, stdin);
   printf("Enter experience_year of teacher : ");
   fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
   sscanf(line, "%d",&th[i].experience_year);
 }
 ...
```

And in really good practices (in fact everything that could be used in real workd) you should **always** test the result of input functions (left as an exercise for the reader in above code :-) )

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the number of teachers that is t you enter a \n after the integer which stays in your buffer and is accepted as input in gets statement. Therefore use a getchar after entering integer to solve the problem.

```
int t,i;
printf("Enter how many teachers are in department\n");
scanf("%d",&t);
getchar();
```

and add another getchar after the scanf in the for loop.

```
scanf("%d",&th[i].experience_year);
getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < conio.h >
void main()
{
    char name[3][100], add[3][100];
    int i;
    printf("ENTER YOUR DETAIl:");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("ENTER NAME:  ");
        gets(name[i]);
        printf("ENTER ADDRESS: ");
        gets(add[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n___________________\n");
        printf("\nNAME:%s", name[i]);
        printf("\Address:%s", add[i]);
        printf("\n___________________\n");
    }

    getch();
}
```

You can use this way in c programming. If your program does not take a string with spaces as input for multiple string type of input.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

This function will clear your input buffer.

Comment: this can be used in case of structure too

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fflush(stdin);
```

before every `gets()`